# SharePoint 2013 Lookup column

Tags: 2013, lookup-column

How to fetch I'd of the parent list from a lookup column value. I have created a report using jQuery data table in child  list.( Ihave the lookup column in this  list which is referring to the parent list) .I want to make the lookup column clickable in the report and redirect to parent list disp form

Comment: You can directly form the URL like `/<site collection>/Lists/ListName/DispForm.aspx?ID=<LookupItemID>`

Comment: How to get the LookupItemID

Comment: How you are showing the lookup items in your report. can you share your script

Answer (score 0):

If you used the Rest API then the query should be as below

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List Title')/items?$select=LookUpField/Title, LookUpField /Id&$expand= LookUpField
```

Here you have to expand the LookUpField to get the id as shown above. Then you can get the ID in your success method as below.

```
Function Success(items){
 if(items.length > 0)
    var lookupValue = (items[0]. LookUpField.Title;   
    var lookupID = items[0]. LookUpField.Id;
```

}

Use this id to open your parent list item

```
{site collection}/Lists/ListName/DispForm.aspx?ID={lookupID}
```

Comment: It is returning ID=UNDEFINED

Comment: Can you please post your code, which is being used to fetch the list items?